# Color inheriting with different properites

Tags: css, inheritance, font-awesome

This is my code structure:

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <span class="fa fa-home" style="position:absolute"></span>
</div>
```

I need to change the icon color (using font-awesome) which should be same as border-color of the div which has the class 'divider'. Whenever I change the border color of the divider then the icon color should shift to the border color of the divider.

Comment: Inheritance only works for children..since the span is not a child of the divider div...it can't inherit anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` selector in CSS, which selects the [elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp):

```
.divider + .fa {
    /* the .fa itself */
}

.divider.blue + .fa {
    /* when .divider has class "blue", apply these rules to "fa" */
}
```

Comment: yes.. thank you.. i can select the next element but am unable to inherit the border color of the divider to color of the font icon

Comment: That's impossible. You can only (and only) inherit from a parent. The preceding div is not the parent; therefore inheritance is impossible.